# Métodos "__" ou "Dunder" em Python, quais são os mais utilizados?

Tags: python-3.x

Em Python existem os métodos "Mágicos", como o `__len__`, que permite o uso do len(object), além desse em especifico, quais são os outros mais utilizados que possam facilitar o uso da estrutura ?

Comment: Você encontra uma lista bastante razoável com explicações bem extensas: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 15):

Os métodos especiais ou mágicos em Python são utilizados para que definir um comportamento específico para uma classe quando determinada operação for operada.

Por exemplo, existem situações onde você poderá definir um comportamento quando o objeto dessa classe for tratada como `str` ou ainda como `float`. Ainda existem outros casos onde você pode definir comportamentos quando o objeto for chamado como função, se ele for utilizado em operações de comparação ou operações matemáticas. Enfim, o Python ofereceu uma grande gama de métodos especiais para que você possa personalizar o comportamento de sua classe.

A lista de métodos mágicos que podem ser usadas em Python é [bem grande](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php).
Então vou postar apenas alguns exemplos aqui:

## `__str__`

É invocado quando o objeto é invocado como `str`.

Exemplo:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'is my class'


obj = MyClass();

print("This " + str(obj))
```

O resultado será: `"This is my class"`

## `__call__`

É invocado quando o objeto é invocado como função.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return 'Hello World!'


obj = MyClass();

print(obj())
```

Resultado é `"Hello World!"`

## `__init__`

É utilizado para inicializar a classe.

Exemplo:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name   


p = Person('Wallace');

print(p.name)
```

Resultado: `"Wallace"`

## `__float__`

Quando você define esse método, sua classe passa a ter o comportamento determinado por ele quando houver uma tentativa de usar a instância dessa classe como o tipo  `float`.

Veja:

```
class Numero(object):

    def __float__(self):
        return 1.11111



print(float(Numero()))
```

O resultado será: `1.11111`

Creio que tendo exemplos de `__str__` e `__float` na minha resposta, torna-se dispensável falar da existência de `__int__`, `__bytes__`, `__dict__`, já que eles vão trabalhar de formas semelhantes para cada tipo.

## Outros métodos

Há também vários métodos mágicos utilizados para personalizar operações de comparação.

- `__lt__`: Menor que (less than)
- `__le__`: Menor ou igual (less or equal)
- `__eq__`: Igual (equals)
- `__ne__`: Não igual (not equal)
- `__ge__`: Maior ou igual (greather or equal)
- `__gt__`: - Maior que (greather than)

Todos os métodos acima são invocados quando você utiliza uma expressão comparativa. Geralmente, eles recebem um parâmetro que deverá ser comparado com um valor da classe atual.

Exemplo `__eq__`:

```
class Numero(object):
    def __init__(self, numero):
        self.numero = numero   

    def __eq__(self, a):
        print("Chamou __eq__")
        print(a.numero)


a = Numero(1)
b = Numero(2)

a == b
b == a
```

O resultado será:

```
"Chamou __eq__"
2
"Chamou __eq__"
1
```

Leia mais em [Standard operators as function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html)

Comment: Já ganhou o meu +1, mas eu sugiro complementar a resposta com alguns exemplos bem simples. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira eu estou elaborando :p

Comment: Só um detalhe, o "__init__" é um inicializador, o "__new__" é um construtor, esses mais básicos eu conheço, já os de comparação eu não conhecia.

Comment: @ArthurSilva eu não sabia do `__new__`, kkkkkk

Comment: Galera, preciso voltar a trabalhar agora. Qualquer coisa, é só falar, que mais tarde eu edito.

Comment: @Miguel pode editar, realmente tinha pensado nisso. Agora tô meio sem tempo :p

Comment: Qual seria o motivo de você passar o `self` como parâmetro do método `__init__()` explicitamente?

Comment: @lucasmoraes, isso faz parte da especificação do Python. "Melhor explícito do que implícito"