# Como criar operadores em Python?

Tags: python, operadores

Eu estava pesquisando na internet sobre porque o Python não tem o operador `++` e vi alguém dizendo que dá pra criar esse operador.

Como se faz isso? Como criar um operador em Python?

Comment: Não pode ser só '+= 1' ?  ou  '+= valor' , '+=' substitui o '++' em certos casos

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**atualização para o Python 3.8**

A resposta e considerações abaixo são de 2017, e continuam válidas.

Mas em outubro de 2019, foi lançado o Python 3.8 com o novo operador de "Assignment Expressions" - popularmente chamado de "Walrus operator" por lembrar um emoji ASCII de uma morsa (walrus): `:=` .

Com o uso desse operador e parênteses, pode-se efetivamente emular as formas prefixas de `++` e `--` - de forma mais verbosa, mas sem nenhum dos efeitos colaterais abaixo - é só escrever:

`y = (x:= x + 1)`  para ter o equivalente a `y = ++x` (e a mesma substituição em qualquer expressão mais complexa).
A forma pós-fixa, que retorna o valor atual e na sequência altera o valor da variável continua sem equivalente.

**resposta original:**

Tem alguns fatores envolvidos aí - resumindo: pode ser "possível" criar alguma forma de "++" e "--" - mas terão limitações, e, esse operador em particular, viola uma das premissas da linguagem - então mesmo sendo possível, não quer dizer que seja uma boa ideia.

## Customizaçao de operadores

Então, por partes: como está nas outras respostas, em Python é possível definir o comportamento dos operadores existentes nas classes que você cria para você mesmo.

Para isso, basta você colocar na sua classe algum dos métodos com nome pré-definido - como está no [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) da linguagem.

Isso permite que os objetos que você define, (e até classes), possam fazer o que quiserem com os operadores, aritméticos ou não, binários já definidos: `- + * @ / // % ** ^ | & in << >>`  e talvez algum outro que eu tenha esquecido - e permite mudar o comportamento para alguns operadores unários (alguns dos quais são aplicados com a chamada de uma função):  `not len + -`, e até operadores de `"augmented assignment":` += -= *=`, etc...
Operadores que usem outros símbolos dos que o que já estão mapeados, como seria o caso de novos "++" e "--" não podem ser definidos desta forma.

## Separação de expressão e atribuição

Primeiro, vamos entender por que Python não tem esses operadores para começar:  uma das premissas do Python é tentar manter o código bem legível e mantível, com menos propenção a erros. Então desde o começo do Python, qualquer coisa que atribua um valor a uma variável (assignment) é um "comando" (statement), não é uma expressão. Isso significa que você não pode, ordinariamente, alterar valores de variáveis dentro de uma expressão, seja dentro de um `if` ou outro comando, dentro de um parênteses para calcular parâmetros para uma função, ou a direita de um sinal de igual.

Para ficar claro, em C, e as linguagens derivadas, como Java, Javascript, etc... isso aqui é válido:

```
a = 0;
b = 1;
a = (b = 3) + 1;
```

e a terceira linha modificará a variável `b`, e a `a` baseada no novo valor de `b`. Em Python isso é ilegal, por que o "=" não é um "operador", ele é um "statement" e não pode ser parte de uma expressão.
Isso exige uma linha a mais quando se quer escrever expressões desse tipo, por outro lado evita "erros" do tipo:

```
if (user.gid = 0){
    // usuário é root, validar operação
}
```

Veja  o que era pra ser um teste se o id do usuário é 0, não só sempre dá certo, como ainda transforma aquele usuário em id 0 dali pra frente, por que digitaram `=` em vez de `==`.

Então, mesmo nos operadores de augmented assignment - `+= *=`, etc, que você pode criar para os seus objetos - você pode alterar a parte que "faz a conta" - mas a atribuição do resultado final para a variável à esquerda do operador é feita pela linguagem, e não dá pra mexer nisso.
Ou seja, nesse código:

```
a  = MeuObjeto()
a += 5
```

O Python vai chamar o método `MeuObjeto.__iadd__` com os parâmetros `self` (a própria instância `a`) e o valor `5`. Esse método faz operações e retorna um valor - esse valor é atribuido a variável a. Se o objeto for "mutável" e ele puder fazer a operação "nele mesmo", sem criar uma nova instância, ele deve retornar `self`. Senão, ele retorna uma nova instância, a instância anterior é "esquecida" e apagada pelo garbage colector, e a vida continua.

*nb*:  A regra de "variáveis não podem ser alteradas dentro de expressões" não é uma "mágica" - ela se aplica ao uso da sintaxe dos operadores de atribuição. Python permite que a maior parte dos valores que tem associados a nomes seja alterado por chamadas de funções e métodos, tais como `setattr` e `__setitem__`  - como essas chamadas podem ser usadas dentro de uma expressão, é possível alterar alguns valores - com a not[avel exceção de variáveis locais e não locais. (Para variáveis globais, você pode colocar, dentro de uma expressão `globals().__setitem__("nome_da_variavel", valor)` )

Bom, se deu pra entender por que Python não permite a mudança de valores dentro variáveis dentro de uma expressão, é fácil perceber que os operadores `++` e `--` fazem exatamente isso - e por isso não foram inclusos na linguagem.

## Objetos imutáveis

Ainda há no entanto uma *outra* razão pela qual esses operadores em particular não funcionariam com números em Python: Os números nativos em Python são  objetos imutáveis - ou seja, uma vez criados com um valor, aquele valor não pode ser alterado "inplace". O uso de operadores como `+=` numa variável numérica na verdade criam um outro objeto númerico e atribui o novo objeto à variável. Experimente fazer:

```
a = 0
print (id(a))
a += 1
print(id(a))
```

No modo interativo do cpython você vai ver id's distintos, indicando que o nome `a` aponta para instâncias diferentes. Isso é bem prático para muitas coisas em linguagens dinâmicas, permitindo que os tipos numéricos sejam usados como chaves de dicionários, etc...Para cálculos que usam muita memória e precisam de velocidade, você pode usar outros tipos de dados, como `array.array` e as várias estruturas de dados providas pelo `numpy` para ter tipos numéricos nativos (com 1, 2, 4 ou 8 bytes), que são alterados "in place" na memória nas operações necessárias. Mas uma instância de um int ou float em Python, bem como uma string (str), são imutáveis.

Ou seja, um operador `++` numa variável `a` não poderia alterar o número que é apontado por `a`.

## Novos operadores, só para novos tipos (classes)

Bom, já deve ter sido entendido que só podemos modificar o comportamento de operadores para novas classes. Para classes existentes, como int, float, dict, etc..., só usando coisas como o [Forbidden Fruit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/forbiddenfruit/0.1.0), que permite alterar os tipos nativos de Python alterando a memporia do processo e o comportamento do runtime do Python, e ai ele pode alterar o comportamento de tipos nativos, como é feito na linguagem Ruby.

Se você fizer isso em um programa maior (e muito mais em código para produção), a chance de outros módulos Python que seu sistema usa quebrarem, possivelmente com um segmentation fault é de 950%. No hack a seguir, não vamos fazer isso.

## O escambau! Hackeando tudo isso e fazendo o "++"

Perceba que **nada impede** que você **crie** uma nova classe que se comporte como **um tipo numérico**. Basta implementar as operações que o seu tipo numérico vai suportar usando os métodos descritos no [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). O próprio Python implementa tipos numéricos extras como o `decimal.Decimal` - que até recentemente era implementado em Python puro (agora tem uma implementação em código nativo para maior performance). E o seu tipo numérico pode ser mutável in place. Para ter um tipo bem indistinguível de outros números, você pode marca-lo como uma subclasse de `numbers.Number`.

Para manter a coisa simples, vamos criar um tipo que suporte as operações `+` e `-` binárias, mas que seja alterável "in place". Um tipo desses não pode ser usado como chave de dicionário, mas pode ser usado em contas. Para isso, temos que ter um atributo interno que guarde o valor real do nosso número.
Se implementarmos `__add__`, `__sub__`, podemos usar nosso número com os operadoes `+` e `-`. Se desejar outros operadores, é só implementa-los paulatinamente - (`__mul__`, `__div__`, `__pow__`). Se implementarmos os métodos `__iadd__` e `__isub__` - pronto, nosso número pode ser alterado  "inplace" com os operadores `+=` e `-=`

```
class MutableNumber:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return MutableNumber(self.value + other)
    
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return MutableNumber(self.value + other)
    
    # define __mul__, __div__ and others if desired.
    
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.value += other
        return self
    
    def __isub__(self, other):
        self.value -= other
        return self
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
```

E podemos testar isso no ambiente interativo (eu uso o ipython):

```
In [37]: a = MutableNumber(5)

In [38]: id(a)
Out[38]: 140138783472496

In [39]: a += 10

In [40]: a
Out[40]: 15

In [41]: id(a)
Out[41]: 140138783472496
```

E agora o "hack" possível para implementar o "++" e o "--" passar por esse caminho: o data model preve os operadores unários `+` e `-` e chama os métodos `__neg__` e `__pos__` da classe do objeto. O interpretador simplesmente vai chamar duas vezes seguidas esses métodos se encontrar `++a`, por exemplo. Note que algo como `a++` vai ser um erro de sintaxe, ou, no caso do código ser algo como `a++ + b` o que vai acontecer é `a + (++b)`. Por que o parser não vai entender `++` ele simplesmente interpreta cada `+` como um operador.

Em suma, já que temos nosso tipo mutável, basta implementar um estado interno que saiba se `__pos__` ou `__neg__` foram chamados, e a cada segunda chamada altere o valor.

Note ainda que para isso "funcionar" de forma limpa bem seria necessário ter uma forma de detectar que as duas chamadas em para `__pos__` foram feitas "no mesmo local". Não vamos fazer isso aqui, portanto se você usar `+a` em lugares diferentes do código, vai ocasionar o incremento de valor.
Há dois caminhos para fazer isso: usar "frame introspection" dentro do código dos operadores unários, e verificar se uma chamada foi de fato próoxima a outra no código fonte de origem. E outra é "controlar" todos os usos da classe em todos os métodos especiais (aqueles definidos no data model) possíveis - qualquer chamada intermediária entre duas chamadas ao método unário, reseta o contador.  Podemos fazer isso para os métodos que definimos, pelo menos.

```
class MutableNumber:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.inc_counter = 0
        self.dec_counter = 0

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.reset()
        return MutableNumber(self.value + other)
    
    __radd__ = __add__

    def __sub__(self, other):
        self.reset()
        return MutableNumber(self.value + other)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        self.reset()
        return MutableNumber(other - self.value)

    # define __mul__, __div__ and others if desired.

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.reset()
        self.value += other
        return self

    def __isub__(self, other):
        self.reset()
        self.value -= other
        return self

    def __pos__(self):
        self.inc_counter += 1
        self.dec_counter = 0
        if self.inc_counter == 2:
            self.value += 1
            self.reset()
        return self

    def __neg__(self):
        self.dec_counter += 1
        self.inc_counter = 0
        if self.dec_counter == 2:
            self.value -= 1
            self.reset()
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        self.reset()
        return repr(self.value)
```

(Nesta versão eu implementei também o `__radd__` e `__rsub__`  - as versões "a direita" para as operações de + e - isso permite que esses números possam estar de qualquer lado do operador binário).

E *voilá*:

```
In [53]: a = MutableNumber(0)

In [54]: a
Out[54]: 0

In [55]: b = 2 + ++a

In [56]: b
Out[56]: 3

In [57]: a
Out[57]: 1
```

Lembrando que basta estender a implementação para ter `__mul__`, `__rmul__` e os outros operadores, para fazerem contas com `self.value` como acima e essa classe pode ser usada como um tipo numérico normal. Em particular implemente também `__int__` e `__float__` retornando `__self.value__`.

(como autor, declaro para os devidos fins que este código está sob a [licença padrão do stackoverflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4685/licen%C3%A7a-mit-como-utilizar-c%C3%B3digos-do-stack-overflow), ou pode ser usado sob a LGPL v3.0)

Comment: A título de curiosidade, achei a resposta excelente. Acho válido comentar que numa implementação assim pode ocorrer um *comportamento estranho*, pois chamando `+++a` e depois `+a`, o valor de `a` será incrementado duas vezes (https://repl.it/NVAB/0), embora o "operador" `++` tenha sido chamado explicitamente apenas em `+++a`. Será que teria alguma forma de impedir isso?

Comment: oi Anderson  - veja o código aí: essa implementação cuida disso. Ela reseta o contador após o incremento,não há dois incrementos com três operadores unários.

Comment: ah  sim, o terceiro "+" incrementa mais "meia vez" o "a" . A única forma de evitar isso é ter introspecção do código fonte de onde a chamada foi feita - tem um parágrafo falando sobre isso acima.  `sys._getframe().f_back, e ai o atributo f_lineno dá o numero da linha, e o atributo .f_code.co_filename o caminho para o arquivo fonte. voce abre o arquivo e faz o parse pra ver como os "++" estão sendo usados.

Sim, isso ficaria bem lento - mas acho que ficou claro que esse código é pra brincar, nao para produção.

Comment: Sim, ficou :D Só foi um teste que me surgiu lendo a resposta e fiquei curioso quanto. Também havia pensado na introspecção, mas achei que pudesse existir outra forma mais simples.

Comment: nao - uma coisa que quando me caiu a ficha foi meiio que "uau" é que para qualquer objeto em Python ser "consumido", ele tem que passar por um dos métodos mágicos.  Seja representação, seriaização, conta...etc.. .então se voce colocar uma chamada ao `reset` em todos os métodos (mágicos e outros que tenha na classe), você fecha bem a coisa. Mas o "meio incremento" em linhas distintas, sem nenhuma operação intermediária, ele não fecha.

Answer (score 11):

A linguagem não provê esta capacidade. É possível criar um comportamento específico para operadores existentes (veja resposta do Math), mas não permitiria criar o `++`. A resposta do jsbueno mostra uma curiosidade interessante, mas não faça isto, é procurar sarna pra se coçar. Se já não bastasse que a linguagem deliberadamente não quis ter este operador, pior ainda forçar a criação dele com truques para enganar o *parser*.

Cuidado para não abusar da sobrecarga de operadores. Nunca faça nada nele que não seja a semântica esperada para ele. Então não faça um `+` ou `+=` se comportar como se fosse um `++`.

Até onde eu sei não é possível modificar o comportamento dos operadores para os tipos primitivos da linguagem, como inteiros.

Há muitos questionamentos se os operadores `++` e `--` são bons. Eu gosto deles e sabendo usar não tem problema, mas eles não são tão intuitivos assim para muita gente e poucos sabem de todas as características e consequências deles. Provavelmente por isto a linguagem preferiu deixá-los de fora.

Quando vê em algum lugar deve pedir fundamentação.

Se colocar onde viu isto talvez eu possa melhorar a resposta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 10):

Em Python você não consegue criar operadores, mas consegue sobrescrevê-los, para isso você precisa reimplementar os [métodos mágicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176465/3117) também conhecidos como *dunders* (abreviação de double underlines). Veja a lista de todos os métodos especiais no [data model da linguagem](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Um exemplo de classe que sobrescreve o método de adição:

```
class Sobrecarga:
    val = 0

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.val)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if other == '+':
            self.val += 1
        else:
            return self.val + other


a = Sobrecarga(1)
print(a)    # saida: 1
a+'+'       # gambi :P
print(a)    # saida: 2
a+1         # resultado da operação não é armazenado
print(a)    # saida: 2
print(a+1)  # saida: 3
```

Não é exatamente o que você quer, pois o operador `+` foi sobrecarregado para quando o parâmetro for o string literal `+` somar o `self.val` em 1 e armazenar o novo valor nele mesmo, mas se tentar fazer `a++` vai dar erro de sintaxe pois isso não pode ser interpretado em Python. Para todos os outros casos a operação de soma vai fazer a operação normal de soma e retornar o valor.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ttrzf0)

Comment: é legal por um link para o documento do data model da linguagem, que lista todos os métodos especiais: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: @jsbueno boa dica, feito