# O que significa __*(qualquer palavra)__ ou _* no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lendo um livro de vez em quando ele coloca `__init__` ou `__init` e eu não sei o que esses "_" significa, tentei procurar na internet algumas explicações, porém acabei me dificultando mais, alguém poderia me auxiliar explicando de forma mais prática?

Comment: Relacionada: [Métodos “__” ou “Dunder” em Python, quais são os mais utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176465/4808)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gambiarra :)

Estas coisas foram inseridas na linguagem muito tarde, como estes identificadores poderiam já estar sendo usados por códigos existentes em Python precisava fazer alguma coisa para não quebrar os códigos existentes e como o `__` [é "reservado"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) resolvia a questão.

Estes identificadores são para membros "mágicos" da linguagem, portanto não é um nome comum, é algo que a linguagem trata de forma especial e gera algo específico.

O `__init__` por exemplo é um método que inicializará o objeto, o que você escrever ali será executado toda vez que um objeto for instanciado. A linguagem o chamará por você.Então ele não é um método qualquer, a presença dele no seu código diz para a linguagem o que ela deve fazer.

A explicação oficial é que isto é para diferenciar que é uma função "mágica", mas ela não é consistente.

[image: Bug Feature e By design (três baratas uma mais bem vestida e outra bem vestida mas detonada)]

Comment: Mas não faz sentido, não é por isto que importamos bibliotecas e utilizamos elas em funções depois?

Comment: Mas isto não tema nada a ver com bibliotecas, é construção da linguagem. Você importa para usar `for`, `if`, etc? É a mesma coisa, isto não adiciona função nova alguma, adiciona algo à linguagem.

Comment: Entendi, poderia dar um exemplo de "a linguagem trata como algo especial".

Comment: @ThinKing editei.

Comment: -1 pelo "gamibiarra". Não é - por que essas "coisas" foram inseridas na linguagem junto com o modelo de objetos 0 não é como se já existisse uma base de códigos gigantesca com métodos "init" falsos.  

O diferencial  dos __**__ é proposital para indicar métodos que são chamados internamente pelos mecanismos da linguagem, mas isso é uma opção do design desses métodos, e não uma forma "ad hoc" de evitar colisões.

Comment: Faltou comentar que nas classes de objetos, os métodos e atributos iniciados com `_` (ou `__`, atualmente está se preferindo usar esta sintaxe) não são exportados para novos objetos em caso de herança.